# Does Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID get reset when a device installs a later Android version?

Tags: android

[`Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) is supposed to be used as a unique device identifier, with the advantage that if the device is wiped it is reset; this means if a user sells their device, anything device specific pertaining to that user is not associated with it, which is clearly advantageous.

However, my phone has the Kindle app and when I upgraded from Eclair to Froyo, and again to Gingerbread, the Amazon site registered each new build as a separate device.  This suggests that upgrading a device (as opposed to wiping it) changes the ID.

1. Does it?
2. What is the most reliable means of an installed application recalling the previous device ID across a system upgrade?  (If an application knows its old device ID, it can link the new one to the old one on a remote system, for example.)

Comment: By the way, I'm aware that there may be no 100% reliable means of recalling something across a system upgrade; I want opinions on the means with the lowest probability of failure.

Answer (score 0):

This is device dependent. So if you have a strong requierment on it being uniqe you need to find something else. For identification of a user i would suggest login with username and password and a MD5 hash of this stored serverside.
Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID will work on most devices, but as you already stated, not on al, som will retan it after a upgrade or reset, some wont. Some devices have the same id, that is al devices of a specific manufacturer will have the same ID.
Read more here [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)